# Do Travis CI could compile Sass?

Tags: sass, gulp, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I would to know if Travis CI, or another CI tool, can compile scss files into css via Gulp tasks.
Actually my .travis.yml file look like this:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  #Version de NodeJS à utiliser
  - "8"

before_install:
  #Installation de npm et modules selon package.json
  - npm install

before_script:
  # Installation des modules avec npm
  - npm install -g gulp-cli
  - npm install --save-dev gulp@^3.0.0
  - npm install --save-dev gulp-load-plugins
  - npm install --save-dev browser-sync
  - npm install --save-dev autoprefixer gulp-postcss
  - npm install --save-dev gulp-cache
  - npm install enquire.js
  - npm install browser-sync --save-dev

script:
  #lancement de la tache Gulp par défaut pour compiler - sinon spécifier tache
  #- gulp
  - gulp localcompile
```

But this is relauched if I push a scss modified file, and no compilation at the end.
If someone can tell me how to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

YAML can be overwhelming. I had the same issue - I had no idea how to properly configured it. But I am using Buddy where I can just copypaste my YAML or just use thier UI to simply drag-and-drop my pipeline. Below you can see the YAML from my Buddy pipeline with Gulp

```
- pipeline: "TestDeploy"
  trigger_mode: "MANUAL"
  ref_name: "master"
  ref_type: "BRANCH"
  trigger_condition: "ALWAYS"
  actions:
  - action: "Execute: gulp js"
    type: "BUILD"
    working_directory: "/buddy/mypage"
    docker_image_name: "library/node"
    docker_image_tag: "latest"
    execute_commands:
    - "npm install"
    - "gulp style"
    - "gulp js"
    setup_commands:
    - "npm install -g gulp"
    volume_mappings:
    - "/:/buddy/mypage"
    trigger_condition: "ALWAYS"
    shell: "BASH"
  - action: "Compress images"
    type: "IMAGE_COMPRESSION"
    local_path: "img-build/"
    destination: "/img/"
    level: "1"
    types: "jpg,png,gif,svg"
    trigger_condition: "ALWAYS"
  - action: "Deploy FTP"
    type: "FTP"
    input_type: "BUILD_ARTIFACTS"
    local_path: "/"
    remote_path: "/mypageonline.com"
    login: "paul.rowly@aol.com"
    password: "secure!NE4NYgVsAs+E9dmVQXCDOw==.Uo/dYie/3WS+iSS0Z0xmaA=="
    host: "mypageonline.com"
    port: "21"
    deployment_excludes:
    - "/node_modules/"
    - "/assets/js-build/"
    - "/assets/sass/"
    - ".idea"
    - ".gitignore"
    - "/img-build/"
  - action: "Send notification to Telegram"
    type: "TELEGRAM"
    content: "[#$BUDDY_EXECUTION_ID] [$BUDDY_PROJECT_NAME]($BUDDY_PROJECT_URL)  execution by $BUDDY_EXECUTION_REVISION_COMMITTER_NAME"
    parse_mode: "MARKDOWN"
    trigger_condition: "ALWAYS"
    integration_hash: "5dde3440422f5a6e5bb72f0d"
```

let me know if that helped.

below is the GUI version of my yaml.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y2t3.png)